# Open and save .iqy to table from script

Tags: excel, bash, powershell, sharepoint, cmd

I'm looking for a way to open a .iqy file from script and save the file that i get.
Context: Where I work we currently try to automate the process of renaming building elements. For those we have the properties saved in an SharePoint Excel file and we want to find a 1-Click-Solution, where a programm fetches the data from the SharePoint tables and uses ArchiCAD API to get those changes into the project.

If anyone knows a comfortable way to get the data from SharePoint (tried REST API with not much success) or the .iqy file, i would be very grateful :)

Kind Regards
Dayiz1

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation available at [SharePoint PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/)? There are PowerShell modules available to connect to Sharepoint (both on-prem as well as 365)

Comment: Not yet, ill take a look. Thank you!